# Blender 2.80 and Windows 7

Tags: windows, installation, compatibility

I try to open Blender 2.80 on Windows 7 and nothing happens.

I have never had problems with previous versions on my machine, it works perfectly under Ubuntu (my second machine).

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Could your Win 7 machine have an older video card with less than OpenGL 3.3 drivers?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you possibly are trying to use the same blender download file for both Ubuntu and Windows, in which case you would need to download the windows file for blender 2.8: https://builder.blender.org/download/, although with the level of detail you have provided it is rather hard to tell. Could you state what machine you are using, where you downloaded the blender file from, and anything else that is non-orthodox about your setup.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Windows7 too and I had problem with using blender 2.8 or above. Anyway I can use it now, on the other hand I have some more preblems to solve.

My first advice is to update your drivers with an app or manually.
If it doesnt works then you can go to this link.[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FzyfPMlVVE&t=205s)

In the video, the guy is not talking English but If you need help virtually you can watch him.

Only thing that you need to do is go to [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19teTBNis9jRk99gEt991-SyTVxSaiDwv/view) 
download the zip file then extract the .dll file to wherever you want. Then copy that .dll file and paste it to the where your blender.exe is.

At the second solution you might have take low fps in the editor ( even I had some crashes).

I hope it works for you :)

P.S : If you do the second process and then update your drivers you will need to delete that .dll file.